# Why is this string array empty?

Tags: c#, arrays

Cant figure out why this isnt working? When I console.writeline the values inside the loop, newFruits contains the correct values.
All I get is System.String[] as the output

```
 public static string[] FuncSortItemsInList(string[] fruits)
        {
            Array.Sort(fruits);
            Array.Reverse(fruits);
            string[] newFruits = new string[fruits.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i< fruits.Length; i++)
            {              
                newFruits[i] = fruits[i];              
            }
            return newFruits; 
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            //Food.SortItemsInList(new string[] { "Banana", "Apple", "Pineapple" }); 
            Console.WriteLine(Food.FuncSortItemsInList(new string[] { "Banana", "Apple", "Pineapple" }));
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you are using an IDE like visuals tudio, paying attention to the popup that shows the function signature might help. `Console.WriteLine` accepts and prints a single string among other overloads, but not an array of strings in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not empty, `Console.WriteLine(object)` overload is being called in this case since you did not specify any format string. That overload calls `ToString()` on the object passed in, which in your case is a `string[]`.

To get the intended output, you need to write code like this

```
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", Food.FuncSortItemsInList(new string[] { "Banana", "Apple", "Pineapple" }));
```

Comment: Thanks - is it possible to have the items displayed on a line-by-line basis as opposed to joined together?

Comment: It is definitely possible. But look for that in the documentation itself. See details for `string.Join()` and how to represent newlines in strings. SO is not a code-writing service. There are multiple ways to output string array in different lines, you are better off learning those on your own by looking at documentation.

Comment: @Jayware33 replace `", "` with `Environment.NewLine` in the `string.Join`